# deleting some parts of requested href attrs in bs4

Tags: python, regex, beautifulsoup, python-requests

I need slugs of all articles on a page. I used bs4 to get href contents of all articles, but some article's link has another URL which I don't need it. I want to delete those items. I used this code:

```
import requests
import re
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup



r = requests.get('https://davidventuri.medium.com/')


soup = BeautifulSoup(r.text, 'html.parser')
all_slugs = soup.find_all('a', {'class': 'dn br'})

for i in range(len(all_slugs)):
    slug = all_slugs[i]['href']
    print(slug)
```

Here is my result of getting hrefs:

```
/this-is-not-a-real-data-science-degree-d170c660c1cf

/not-a-real-degree-data-science-curriculum-2021-19ba9af2c1d4

/bitcoin-learning-path-9ed73f2f11d9

/your-first-day-of-school-eaf363b19ded

https://medium.com/free-code-camp/an-overview-of-every-data-visualization-course-on-the-internet-9ccf24ea9c9b

https://medium.com/free-code-camp/the-best-data-science-courses-on-the-internet-ranked-by-your-reviews-6dc5b910ea40

https://medium.com/free-code-camp/every-single-machine-learning-course-on-the-internet-ranked-by-your-reviews-3c4a7b8026c0

https://medium.com/free-code-camp/dive-into-deep-learning-with-these-23-online-courses-bf247d289cc0

/how-ai-is-revolutionizing-mental-health-care-a7cec436a1ce

https://medium.com/free-code-camp/i-ranked-all-the-best-data-science-intro-courses-based-on-thousands-of-data-points-db5dc7e3eb8e
```

**Actually I want them as below:**

```
/this-is-not-a-real-data-science-degree-d170c660c1cf

/not-a-real-degree-data-science-curriculum-2021-19ba9af2c1d4

/bitcoin-learning-path-9ed73f2f11d9

/your-first-day-of-school-eaf363b19ded

/an-overview-of-every-data-visualization-course-on-the-internet-9ccf24ea9c9b

/the-best-data-science-courses-on-the-internet-ranked-by-your-reviews-6dc5b910ea40

/every-single-machine-learning-course-on-the-internet-ranked-by-your-reviews-3c4a7b8026c0

/dive-into-deep-learning-with-these-23-online-courses-bf247d289cc0

/how-ai-is-revolutionizing-mental-health-care-a7cec436a1ce

/i-ranked-all-the-best-data-science-intro-courses-based-on-thousands-of-data-points-db5dc7e3eb8e
```

How can I delete them with regex or sth else?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the substring to `replace` is always the same, you can go without `regex` like this:

```
slug = a['href'].replace('https://medium.com/free-code-camp','')
```

**Example**

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

r = requests.get('https://davidventuri.medium.com/')
soup = BeautifulSoup(r.text, 'html.parser')

all_slugs = soup.find_all('a', {'class': 'dn br'})

for a in all_slugs:
    slug = a['href'].replace('https://medium.com/free-code-camp','')
    print(slug)
```

**Output**

```
/this-is-not-a-real-data-science-degree-d170c660c1cf
/not-a-real-degree-data-science-curriculum-2021-19ba9af2c1d4
/bitcoin-learning-path-9ed73f2f11d9
/your-first-day-of-school-eaf363b19ded
/an-overview-of-every-data-visualization-course-on-the-internet-9ccf24ea9c9b
/the-best-data-science-courses-on-the-internet-ranked-by-your-reviews-6dc5b910ea40
/every-single-machine-learning-course-on-the-internet-ranked-by-your-reviews-3c4a7b8026c0
/dive-into-deep-learning-with-these-23-online-courses-bf247d289cc0
/how-ai-is-revolutionizing-mental-health-care-a7cec436a1ce
/i-ranked-all-the-best-data-science-intro-courses-based-on-thousands-of-data-points-db5dc7e3eb8e
```

---

### Edit

You can also use `split()`

```
slug = a['href'].split('/')[-1]
```

**Example**

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

r = requests.get('https://davidventuri.medium.com/')
soup = BeautifulSoup(r.text, 'html.parser')

all_slugs = soup.find_all('a', {'class': 'dn br'})

for a in all_slugs:
    slug = a['href'].split('/')[-1]
    print(slug)
```

Comment: Actually the problem is they are not always constant.

Comment: @Hani: Edited my answer and added `split()` as a non regex solution.